# Faster method to find data using search word?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, methods, arrays

I need to search through a string array to find every occurrence of "Parameters Table", and between each "Parameters Table" and the next, get another string from a specified index (that remains constant). I have been doing this like so:

```
public List<string> findlistOfNames(string[] arrayToLookForNames)
{
    List<string> listOfNames = new List<string>();

    const string separator = "Parameters Table"; //This is the string I am searching for

    var cuttedWords = arrayToLookForNames.SkipWhile(x => x != separator).Skip(1);

    while (cuttedWords.Any())
    {
        var variable = cuttedWords.TakeWhile(x => x != separator).ToArray();
        cuttedWords = cuttedWords.Skip(variable.Length + 1);
        listOfNames.Add(variable[2]); //This (always index 2) needs to be added to the list
    }
    return listOfNames;
}
```

This runs very slowly. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Here is a snippet of `string[] arrayToLookForNames`:

> Parameters Table
>
> 0
>
> 41
>
> Baro Pressure
>
> hPa
>
> AFD2
>
> recorded
>
> Parameters Table
>
> 0
>
> 42
>
> Baro Setting
>
> in-hg

Comment: It seems that your code a) currently works, and b) you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opionionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Before your post over there (if you do) add in at least an example of the data you are passing into the function.

Comment: Using `Take`/`Skip`/`TaksWhile`/`SkipWhile` here makes the entire thing really inefficient. You should use indexer access instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54431/faster-method-to-find-data-using-search-word

Comment: That is my post as per your suggestion

Comment: @user2340818, I did not write that comment, it was auto-inserted when I voted to close using that close reason.

Comment: @user2340818 : so how many matches would you expect from the above example. I see one (because anything after the last `Parameters Table` is not wrapped)

Comment: @spender it is actually intended to match two, but I didn't realize that it fails to do this until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you haven't specified what happens in the following case:

```
Parameters TableewfihweifhweParameters TableihwefwihewfParameters Table
```

where there are a total of 3 possible matches, I've chosen to assume that there's only one match per entry.

You could use regular expressions to state this somewhat more succinctly. Will probably be more efficient than your method too...

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=Parameters Table).*?(?=(?:Parameters Table)|$)");
IEnumerable<string> foundValues = 
            arrayToLookForNames.SelectMany(x => regex.Matches(x))
                   .Where(m => m.Success)
                   .Select(m => m.Value);
```

... for the entry above, this would yield `ewfihweifhwe`

to cater for your better specified requirements:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=Parameters Table).*?(?=(?:Parameters Table)|$)",
                      RegexOptions.Singleline);
var vals = arrayToLookForNames
               .SelectMany(x=>regex.Matches(x).Cast<Match>())
               .Where(m=>m.Success)
               .Select(m=>m.Value);
```

Comment: There will be multiple occurrences of "Parameters Table" in arrayToLookForNames if that is what you're asking?

Comment: @user2340818 in which case your question is ill-specified... what would the matches for my example above be?

Comment: ah I see the problem. see the edit in my OP please.

Comment: The example in my edit would return listOfNames with: Baro Pressure, Baro Setting

Comment: @user2340818 : I don't really get it, but I provided a variant that might be of use to you.